# NestJS - Find the user wtih a decorator

Tags: javascript, node.js, cpanel, nestjs

In the NestJS framework, I wrote this decorator in order to have access to the logged-in user. I use the JWT strategy. Everything works perfectly in localhost, but when I host my API (on planethoster, via CPanel), the user is no longer present in the object "ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest()" so that all my requests return "401 Unauthorized".

I have no idea where this could come from. Help would be very much appreciated! Thank you very much.

```html
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Client } from '../shared/entities/client.entity';

export const GetClient = createParamDecorator(
    (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) : Client => {
        const client = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest().user;
        if (!client)
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        return client;
    }
);
```

Here is the content of ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest() in localhost :

```html
{
  ...
  body: {},
  route: Route {
    path: '/api/client-auth/check-token',
    stack: [ [Layer] ],
    methods: { get: true }
  },
  authInfo: undefined,
  user: Client {
    id: 1,
    ...
  },
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

And here is the content of ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest() when the API is hosted :

```html
{
  ...
  body: {},
  route: Route {
      path: '/api/client-auth/check-token',
      stack: [ [Layer] ],
      methods: { get: true }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your decorator is not really a guard. All you check if user exists or not. Is your Bearer in  headers or somehow else? How does you logic for JwtPayload looks like? Do you have class for it? Decorator should be simple for this. Something like /**
 * ```
 * async profile(@Auth() auth: AuthToken): Promise<any> { }
 * ```
 */
export const Auth = createParamDecorator((_, req: any) => {
    if (req && req.user instanceof AuthToken) {
        return req.user as AuthToken;
    }
    return undefined;
});

Comment: My decorator isn't a guard, its a decorator used in params to have a direct access to the logged-in user's entity. For the guard, I use the nestjs builtin on, that looks like :

@UseGuards(AuthGuard('client-jwt'))

It automatically does the auth logic with the AuthToken

Comment: How does `req.user` get populated in the first place?